# SQL/ Postgresql How to group on column but find the average of another column based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have an existing table called **sites** which have one or more entries with the same site_id. 
I need to create a new table with the following criteria:

1) If there is more than one entry with the same site_id, I have to check the azimuth values of both the entries with the same site_id and if the difference is less than 10, then get an average of the azimuth value and a single entry is created in the new table for them. (see site_id 5 in the existing table which gets id 6 in the new table)

2) if the 2 entries for the same site_id are more than 10 degrees, then each get a different id in the new table. (See site_id 4 in the existing table which get 2 id's 4 and 5 in the new table)

3) All the other entries which have distinct site_id can be copied over as is and each gets a new id in the new table. (All site_ids except 4 and 5 in the existing table)

EXISTING TABLE **SITES**:

```
            site_id azimuth longitude latitude  
            ------- ------- --------- --------- 
            1       10     -10.93    10.22  
            2       20      5.937    60.43  
            3       30     -7.942    53.47 
            4       70      57.94    13.14  ---> A) Difference of more than 10 degrees with entry below
            4       10      57.94    13.14  ---> A) Difference of more than 10 degrees with entry above

            5       45     -7.92     56.88 --> B) Diff of less than 10 deg with below entry
            5       55     -7.92     56.88 --> B) Diff of less than 10 deg with above entry
```

EXPECTED TABLE with additional id column :

```
            id      site_id azimuth longitude latitude  
            ------- ------- ------- --------- --------- 
             1         1       10     -10.93    10.22  
             2         2       20      5.937    60.43  
             3         3       30     -7.942    53.47 

             4         4       70      57.94    13.14  // A) Since the difference in azimuth between the 2 entries in above table is more than 10 degrees, each entry goes as separate entries in the new table 

             5         4       10      57.94    13.14   // A) Since the difference in azimuth between the 2 entries in above table is more than 10 degrees, each entry goes as separate entries in the new table

             6         5       50     -7.92     56.88   // B) The azimuth was within 10 degrees with the other entry, so the average of 45+55/2=50 is taken as azimuth for site_id 5
```

Since I have to find the average of azimuths based on the 10 degree difference criteria, my aggregate GROUP BY does not work for all entries.
I'm a novice at SQL and would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: What if there are more than two entries?

Comment: If there are more than 2 entries with the same site_id, then the maxAzimuthDifference between any 2 entries within the same site_id should not exceed 20 degrees. Else all of them get a different id in the new table.

Comment: . . I would recommend asking a *new* question with that information, after you have accepted an answer to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a two-step process:

- Step 1: create a table grouping by site_id that determines if the sites with that site_id should be combined or not
- Step 2: join this with the original table to pull in the non-combined data where necessary

The result is the below:

```
select row_number() over () AS id
 , s2.site_id
 , case when t.close_azimuths then avg_azimuth else s2.azimuth end as azimuth
 , s2.longitude
 , s2.latitude
from 
  (select site_id
   , max(azimuth) - min(azimuth) <= 10 as close_azimuths
   , avg(azimuth) as avg_azimuth
  from sites
  group by site_id ) t
join sites s2 on s2.site_id = t.site_id

group by s2.site_id
 , case when t.close_azimuths then avg_azimuth else s2.azimuth end
 , s2.longitude
 , s2.latitude
```

Note that the new azimuth column is not an integer, since it is an average of the integer rows. If the azimuth reading should be an integer you can round and coerce back to integer with ::integer

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question.  One approach is to use window functions to gather all the available information into potential columns.  Then, use simple filtering to determine which columns to take:

```
select site_id,
       (case when max_azimuth - min_azimuth < 10 then avg_azimuth
             else azimuth
        end) as azimuth, longitude, latitude
from (select site_id, azimuth, longitude, latitude,
             row_number() over (partition by site_id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by site_id) as cnt,
             avg(azimuth) over (partition by site_id) as avg_azimuth,
             min(azimuth) over (partition by site_id) as min_azimuth,
             max(azimuth) over (partition by site_id) as max_azimuth
      from sites site_id
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or
      (seqnum = 1 and (max_azimuth - min_azimuth) < 10) or
      (max_azimuth - min_azimuth) >= 10;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,Thanks for your quick reply. If I run the query you mentioned in your reply, I only get entries for site_id 1,2 and 3.  There are no entries for either of the duplicate site_id 4 and 5. Not sure if I'm missing something here.